# How to test non static method was being called by other method using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a method being called by another method.
I don't want to test what the other method do, because this is a separate unit test.

so let's say I have something like:

```
class MyService
    def method_a
      a = 1
      b = method_b
      
      return a + b
    end

    def method_b
      return 2
    end

end
```

Now, I want to test method_a - I want to verify that method_b was executed.

I know that this should work if the methods were static. But in my case, it's not static.

```
allow(MyService).to receive(:method_b)
```

I keep getting this error:
`MyService does not implement method_b`
And I understand that's because the method is not static, but I can't find anything in the documentation that fit my use case.

Comment: I would consider such s test a code smell because it tests internal implementation details instead of behavior or the returned value. Imagine at some point in the future you or another developer decides to refactor method `method_a` and finds a better implementation that doesn't need to call `method_b` anymore. Then your test would break even if the output of `method_a` didn't change at all.

Comment: I agree, but in my case, method_b is essential for this function to work.
without it being called, method_a will break.
Also, in some use cases, I need to use method_b for the return value so I will stub a return value for method_b

I have no other choice actually but to test it.

if in some day someone refactor the code, he can quickly remove the test :)

Comment: @spickermann we can assume that case you described is one of needs specs should cover, if you will rewrite `method_a` in the way where we will not need `method_b` - spec will show it so you'll be able to remove useless method :thinking:

Comment: @OleksandrHolubenko I do not agree. The failing spec will only tell that the `method_a` call doesn't call `method_b` anymore. It still might be used from other methods. Spec should ensure a certain behavior or return values. They should not be written to help you with unused methods. There are other tools to find such methods.

Comment: @spickermann this is pretty tricky question, from one side: as I know such tools you need to run manually, you need to keep them in the project ( yeah, perhaps there are some new tools that might be automated ), but is it worth it to run it on each PR if you can add 1 expect in tests?

From another side, it might be pretty complex logic and `method_b` might be removed accidentally ( let's imagine some example where using of this method is not affect result of running `method_a` ) in this case such test will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think main problem problem is that you expecting for class method to be called and not instance

```rb
describe MyService do
  it "should call method_b" do
    expect(subject).to receive(:method_b).and_return(2)
    subject.method_a
  end
end

# P.S. it's the same as:

describe MyService do
  it "should call method_b" do
    service = MyService.new # instead of MyService.new you can also write described_class.new
    expect(service).to receive(:method_b).and_return(2)
    service.method_a
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh! I understand now what I've missed.

Comment: @engineersmnky  `and_return` needs here to stub `method_b` with value to return, without it it will return `nil`, receive count might be used here too `..and_return(2).once`, `..twice` etc